# Equivalent for nullable value check

Tags: c#, vb.net, nullable

What is the equivalent for this in VB.net

```
int? x;

int s;

s = x ?? 5;
```

Comment: vb.net has also nullable types. like; `Dim x As Integer?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways in vb.net for nullable declaration

```
Dim x? As Integer
Dim x As Integer?
Dim x As Nullable(Of Integer)


Dim s As Integer

s = If(x, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

if() operator is the null coalescing operator in vb.

```
s = If(x, 5)
```